# Why do Qt form edit boxes and labels look different (sizes and location) on Linux Vs via Cygwin?

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, cygwin

We are running a UI developed in Qt 5.2.1. When the UI is viewed via the Cygwin + Xwin interface on a Windows machine, the UI looks good, without any edit boxes moved around. But when it is viewed on the monitor connected to the Linux (Fedora 19) machine, then the edit boxes and other controls on the form are shifted around or the size is different. Since the displays are all telemetry readings, the resizing causes a problem, since we cannot read the data.

Is there a flag that needs to be set or some property of the controls? I am very new to Qt (my first project) and am not sure what is going on.

Comment: You probably don't have the same fonts. And you should show some source code to get help.

Comment: Can you share code/screenshots?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing code and/or screenshots, but you're probably doing something wrong (e.g. manually sizing/positioning controls, hard-coding font sizes, etc). If you use the layout tools correctly, things will generally look OK across platforms even with minor font differences.